# Check if two arrays have a common element

Tags: arrays, sorting, time-complexity

I need to write the psudocode to check if two arrays have a common element within the time complexity of O(n). The code below has the time complexity of O(n^2) but I cant seem to find a way to reduce it. I'm guessing using some type of sort algorithm, but I can figure out the logic. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
for (int i = 0; i<A.length; i++){
    for (int j=0; j<B.length; j++){
        if(A[i]==B[j]){
            return true;
        }
    }
}
return false
```

Comment: No, a sort algorithm will not help you. Have you heard about hash tables?

Comment: @n._m._could_be_an_AI yeah I know what they are, but never used them in practice. Could u help me with an example pseudocode of them for this exercise?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using a hash table, here is the code in javascript:

```
function hasCommonElement(A, B) {
    const hash = {};

    for (const element of A) {
        hash[element] = true;
    }

    for (const element of B) {
        if (hash[element]) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```